# QString::toLocal8Bit() on Windows

Tags: qt, unicode

I have a case which can be summarized like the code below:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QDir>
#include <QCryptographicHash>
#include <iostream>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>

using namespace std;
QString Encode(const QString & filePath)
{
    auto temp = filePath.toLocal8Bit();
    qDebug() << QString("Encode 8 bit: ") << temp;
    return temp.toPercentEncoding(" ");
}

QString Decode(const QString & filePath)
{
    auto temp = filePath.toLocal8Bit();
    qDebug() << QString("Decode 8 bit: ") << temp;
    return QByteArray::fromPercentEncoding(temp);
}


int main()
{
    QString raw = Decode(QString("K%C3%A4ssbohrer"));
    qDebug() << QString("Raw:") << raw;
    QString encoded = Encode(raw);
}
```

And this code outputs:

```
"Decode 8 bit: " "K%C3%A4ssbohrer"
"Raw:" "Kõssbohrer"
"Encode 8 bit: " "K\xE4ssbohrer"
```

As can be seen when I call toLocal8Bit() on a string containing unicode is ending up different with what I initially have. And this problem only happens in windows.

What should I do for making my Encode and Decode functions work mutually 
both in windows and linux? I mean with Encode I want to return a QString which I can use Decode later to obtain the original QString which may contain unicode.

Comment: Why not use `QString::toUtf8`?

Comment: I got this task while trying to fix a bug and not an expert on QString. I tried your suggestion and it worked on windows. Thanks a lot. Maybe you can explain why toUtf8 works and toLocal8Bit does not work and make a answer.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really know it to that level of detail. What I know is that `QString::toLocal8Bit` produces `UTF-8` encoding on Linux and something else on Windows. And since dealing with just about any encoding but `UTF-8` is too painful to even consider, I'd default to dealing with `UTF-8` all the time if there's a choice.

Comment: Have you checked to see what `QTextCodec::codecForLocale()` is set to on each platform?

Comment: @Dmitry I see but thanks a lot man. You already solved my problem I hope some one will come up with explanation.